# facebook canvas session problems in ie

Tags: facebook, session, canvas

I have built an app using the facebook canvas method.  This works in Mozilla but not in IE.  The problem is with a breadcrumbs feature I have using PHP sessions.  In IE  the session is not remembered and the breadcrumb array is overwritten each time instead of appending to the array.

```
session_start();

//get current selected category and add to breadcumbs array
if (isset($_GET['cat_parent_id'])){
    $cat_parent_id = $_GET['cat_parent_id'];
    $cat_name = $_GET['cat_name'];
    if ($cat_parent_id == 0){
        $_SESSION['breadcrumbs'] = '';
    } else {
        //if selected category already in breadcrumb array, remove breadcrumbs after that category
        $position = array_search($cat_parent_id, array_keys($_SESSION['breadcrumbs']));
        // If a position is found, splice the array.
        if ($position !== FALSE) {
            //if ($position == 0){ $position = 1; }
            array_splice($_SESSION['breadcrumbs'], ($position + 1));
        } else {
            $_SESSION['breadcrumbs'][$cat_parent_id] = $cat_name;
        }
    }
} else {
    $cat_parent_id = 0;
    $cat_name = '';
    $_SESSION['breadcrumbs'] = '';
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: that is a solution for ASP.NET and the problem is to do with authentication, which mine does not seem to be...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook iframe not working in IE; session/login issue?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3871199/facebook-iframe-not-working-in-ie-session-login-issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<?php header("p3p: CP=\"ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV\"");?>` 
as answered by Moguzalip works.