# session id regenerates in every reload

Tags: php, facebook, session, iframe, codeigniter-2

I am bulding a canvas facebook page with codeigniter. After user login, rest of the api works with ajax pages. When i make the first ajax call I can't get the session data so I check if session is empty then reload the page. After that i get session in ajax pages. So only after one ajax call and one reload my session_id gets fixed.

If I don't do any ajax call but refresh the page, session id regenerates every time.

All I want to do is load my data to SESSION just one time in the beginning. And be able to use it on my ajax pages.

**UPDATE:** I ve realize it only happens in IE so i found this thread about the issue. But the solution didnt work for me.

[facebook canvas session problems in ie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122106/facebook-canvas-session-problems-in-ie)

header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');

HTACCESS:

```
php_value session.save_path "/tmp"
SetEnv session.use_cookies='1';
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 86400
php_value session.cookielifetime 86400
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  "/PHP_errors.log"
```

CONFIG:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 7200;
```

CONTROLLER:

```
function MyController()
    {
        session_start();
        parent::__construct();
        $this->connectUser();   

    }
function connectUser(){ 
//IF ITS AN AJAX CALL CHECK SESSION AND RELOAD
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
        if (!isset($_SESSION["userid"]) ) {
        echo "AJAX : ".session_id();// the session id on ajax call
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                        window.top.location = 'https://apps.facebook.com/....';
                        </script>";

        }else echo "I have session data on ajax page";

    }
    else{
        echo "PAGE : ". session_id(); // the session id on page load
            if(!isset($_SESSION["userid"])){

                $this->load->library('facebook');                               
                $user = $this->facebook->getUser();

                    if ($user) {
                        try {
                            $data['user_profile'] = $this->facebook->api('/me');

                        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                            $user = null;
                        }
                    }

                    if (isset($data)) {
                        //SET SESSION HERE ....
                        $_SESSION["userid"]=$data['user_profile']["id"];

                    }

                }


        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which Facebook library are you using?

Codeigniter rolls it's own session system via the session class. e.g $this->session->userdata etc rather than using native PHP session ($_SESSION). The session config you have specified relates only to Codigniter's own session implementation.

Read this: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Instead of session_start() autoload the "session" class in your config, or place $this->load->library('session'); at the top of your controller.

The Facebook PHP sdk (https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk) however uses native php sessions in its implementation, although this is abstracted and can be overridden with your own system.

Check out Elliot Haughin's library for an example of working with FB and Codeigniter: https://github.com/elliothaughin/codeigniter-facebook

Comment: I did used codigniter's session class first when i first had this problem i thought codeigniter session was the problem so i used native session but nothing changed. I use latest Facebook PHP SDK (v.3.1.1) . Also i load libraries in autoload : 
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','Template','memcached_library','facebook','session');

Comment: I tried the library you suggested. Its stucked in reload loop because even if i loggin it cant reach my user info.